# Angular UI Bootstrap date-picker Combined With UI.Mask

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui

I am using the angular [UI bootstrap popup date-picker](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepicker) to build a directive that will easily allow me to add the date-picker where need.

When I combine this with the [uiMask Directive](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-utils/), the values in the input get scrambled when I pick a date.

**Here is my html**:

```html
<p class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" 
           ui-mask="99/99/9999"
           ng-model="ngModel" 
           ng-model="order.date" 
           datepicker-popup="MM/dd/yyyy" 
           is-open="opened" 
           datepicker-options="dateOptions" 
           date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" 
           ng-required="true" 
           close-text="Close" />
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open($event)">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
        </button>
    </span>
</p>
```

**And my JS**:

```js
/**
 * DATE PICKER
 */
$scope.today = function () {
    $scope.dt = new Date();
};
$scope.today();

$scope.clear = function () {
    $scope.dt = null;
};

// Disable weekend selection
$scope.disabled = function (date, mode) {
    return (mode === 'day' && (date.getDay() === 0 || date.getDay() === 6));
};

$scope.toggleMin = function () {
    $scope.minDate = $scope.minDate ? null : new Date();
};
$scope.toggleMin();

$scope.open = function ($event) {
    $event.preventDefault();
    $event.stopPropagation();

    $scope.opened = true;
};

$scope.dateOptions = {
    formatYear: 'yy',
    startingDay: 1
};

$scope.initDate = new Date('2016-15-20');
$scope.formats = ['dd-MMMM-yyyy', 'yyyy/MM/dd', 'dd.MM.yyyy', 'shortDate'];
$scope.format = $scope.formats[0];
```

I would like to be able to use the ui-mask functionality to make typing dates easier by not having to type the `/`s. Is it possible to be able to use these together?

Comment: It seems that ui.Mask doesn't exactly work as intended based on the examples they provide [here](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-utils/#mask). Perhaps you should look into an alternative for ui.Mask and see if that's working. This way you can rule out if it's your problem or ui.Mask's problem.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The following snippet worked for me:

```
.config(function ($provide) {

  $provide.decorator('datepickerPopupDirective', function ($delegate) {
    var directive = $delegate[0];
    var link = directive.link;

    directive.compile = function () {
      return function (scope, element, attrs) {
        link.apply(this, arguments);
        element.mask("99/99/9999");
      };
    };

    return $delegate;
  });

});
```

It simply decorates the datepicker directive with a mask provided by **jquery.maskedinput.js**. Have fun!

---

**UPDATE (May 13 2015)**

A plunker to illustrate it working: http://plnkr.co/edit/fTFNu9Mp2kX5X1D6AJOx?p=preview

Comment: i used this pattern element.mask("9999/99/99");

Comment: yes did work for me and date pattern must be like that
"yyyy/MM/dd"

Comment: @IgordeLorenzi or @AminRahimi do either of you have a plunk showing this working?  I'm trying to apply this solution on [this Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/VriiIH?p=preview) but am being told `mask` is not an available method on `element`

Comment: Hi @diplosaurus, you just forgot to include the `jquery` and `jquery.maskedinput.js` dependencies. I updated my answer with your plunker working as expected.

Comment: @IgordeLorenzi Thank you so much, I totally spaced on that one.  Thanks!

Comment: thanks ! It worked for me too.  The last version is:
`$provide.decorator('uibDatepickerPopupDirective'`

Comment: @diplosaurus Nice example. Only, I'm wondering why do we need the formatDate method, removing it does not have any effect in the example. Who executes/calls that method ?

Answer (score 3):

Check out Case 4 in this plunk:
https://plnkr.co/edit/0Vr5YRVREIT5EMu1m55z?p=preview

basically added: added **model-view-value="true"**:

```
<input name="date4" id="date4" type="text" class="form-control" uib-datepicker-popup="dd/MM/yyyy" 
    ui-mask="99/99/9999" placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY" ng-model="date4" ng-required="true" 
    model-view-value="true" is-open="popup4.opened" datepicker-options="dateOptions" 
    show-button-bar="false"/>
<span class="input-group-btn">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open4()"><i class="fa fa-calendar fa-1"></i></button>
</span>
```

Answer (score 2):

When I try to reproduce your challenge, the first thing that comes to mind is:

```
new Date('2016-15-20');
```

returns

```
Invalid Date
```

Perhaps that's a place to start looking for a solution. What date is that? 15th month or the 20th month? Either way, that doesn't work. Provide a valid date for `$scope.initDate`. Perhaps you meant '2016-12-20'?

Can you perhaps create a small example of you situation that we can use to test possible solutions? And what exactly is the 'scrambled input' you are talking about? Again, please provide an example of both the problem and desired outcome.