# Ui mask and datepicker in angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, datepicker, angular-ui

here is the same question : [Angular UI Bootstrap date-picker Combined With UI.Mask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24786796/angular-ui-bootstrap-date-picker-combined-with-ui-mask)
and i can't find any soloution for that .
here is my plunk : http://plnkr.co/edit/i8TBYPonHd1ZxZc9Sac2?p=preview

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <p class="input-group">
       <input type="text" class="form-control" ui-mask="9999/99/99" datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="dt" is-open="opened" min-date="minDate" max-date="'2015-06-22'" datepicker-options="dateOptions" date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" />
       <span class="input-group-btn">
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open($event)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
       </span>
     </p>
</div>
```

the problem is these two directive don't work perfectly together .
Any idea ?
Many thanks

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

```
angular.module('app', [])
    .config(function ($provide) {

      $provide.decorator('datepickerPopupDirective', function ($delegate) {
        var directive = $delegate[0];
        var link = directive.link;

        directive.compile = function () {
          return function (scope, element, attrs) {
            link.apply(this, arguments);
            element.mask("99/99/9999");
          };
        };

        return $delegate;
      });
    });
```

I found this answer here: 
[Angular UI Bootstrap date-picker Combined With UI.Mask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24786796/angular-ui-bootstrap-date-picker-combined-with-ui-mask)

Comment: do you have a plunk showing this working? I'm trying to apply this solution on [this Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/VriiIH?p=preview) but am being told `mask` is not an available method on `element`.  And sure enough if I `console.log` the element `mask` is not on there.

Answer (score 1):

Just add the `jquery.maskedinput.js` script.

Comment: This answer is the only one which worked for me, there's a plunker to illustrate that working: http://plnkr.co/edit/fTFNu9Mp2kX5X1D6AJOx?p=preview. Unfortunately needs jQuery, but works just fine.